# search bar in ActionBar

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I want that search bar below title in Action Bar:

[image]

This is a Navigation Activity. I want the search bar to be like in the picture, which files should I edit?

Answer (score 0):

Make an AppBarLayout and add both a Toolbar and SearchView to it.
Here's the code: (**activity-main.xml**)

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout ... >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar ... />
    <SearchView ... />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Replace `...` with whatever attributes you want to put.